# total number of views of a product in magento

Tags: php, magento

How can i get total number of views of a product in magento
i tried
    $fromDate = '2010-01-01';
    $toDate   = now();

```
$viewedProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addViewsCount($fromDate, $toDate);

foreach($viewedProducts as $product) {
echo "ID: " . $product->getData('entity_id') . " - View Count: " . $product-       >getData('views') . "<br/>";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$id=$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'id');
$fromDate = '2013-12-10';
$toDate   = now();
$viewedProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addViewsCount($fromDate, $toDate);
foreach($viewedProducts as $product) {
if($product->getData('entity_id')==$id)
{
    echo  "Total View Count: " . $product->getData('views');
}}
?>
```